# In a C/C++ program, can you define a global variable that is not accessible by a certain function?

Tags: c++11

Can we define a function as such in C or C++ where a certain function cannot access it?

Comment: Then why are calling it as a `global?`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, I suppose you could create a local variable inside the function with the same name. Then the local variable would be accessed instead of the global one.

Comment: [Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) may help.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a certain function that cannot access a global variable. I was asked this question in a quiz and wanted some answers.

Comment: It is a bad question because, given some global variable and some function, there is always a way to manipulate the source so that the function can access the variable. The question needs to be more specific. If there is no declaration of the global variable in scope where the function is defined, and the function is not allowed to declare it itself (with `extern…`), and nobody passes the address of the variable, directly or indirectly, to the function, and the function does not engage in any undefined behavior, then the function cannot directly access the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ offers you two types of global variables, although many people will probably say that static variables are not global variables...

Now, you can achieve that if you define the global variable after said function. This may not be practical, especially if the variable is defined in a header file because in that case you have to define that function before the #include which may not or even is not likely to be possible.

Now, static variables are specific to the .c or .c++ file where they are defined and often are not viewed as global variables, but they are since they are unique in your program. Static variables can be defined in a separate file making them inaccessible to other functions in other files. (remember that a static variable in C++ is a variable defined inside a namespace without a name.)

In C++, you can also define a variable member that's static. This means the variable is global, but you can make it a private variable. To protect it further, you can define it in a sub-class as a private member. However, either way you'll probably need to gain some form of access to that variable (otherwise it's useless) and thus add functions that return a pointer, a reference, or the current value of that variable...